# One page scrolling site

Tags: html, css

I am new to front end development.  I am trying to create a one page scrolling site.  I have linked my navigation to #divs to scroll within the page- the be-strong link will not see the #be_strong div- 
here is a link:

http://uartsce.com/~sswantak/test/index02A.html#intro_wrapper

Thank you!

Comment: Rules of SO: you must post code relevant to the issue in your question and what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the link should be same as div ID? (be_strong)

Comment: the a href="be_strong" tag matches the #be_strong